# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier always returns nil

Tags: ios

I have a static table with 6 cells and a couple sections. When I initialize a cell it always returns nil, although I have used this exact same method in the passed...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == SAVE_SECTION) {
        ATSaveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SaveCell"];
        if(cell == nil) {
            NSLog(@"nil cell");
            cell = [[ATSaveCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SaveCell"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
        return cell;
    }
```

nil cell is always outputted. In my storyboard, I have a tableviewcontroller that has the cell defined and the id is "SaveCell". I have also checked to make sure the table ciew controller is the same class as the class I am working in... I have used this exact same method in the passed, so I am not sure why the cells are returning nil everytime.

Also, to initialize my tableviewcontroller:

```
ATSearchSettingsViewController *mySearchSettings = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchSettings"];
```

It's pretty clear that the table view is not registering the prototype cells in the storyboard.

Comment: If there are not enough cells to fit the view, it will always create a new one. You can not reuse a cell that is still visible.

Comment: Try to add [self.tableView registerClass:[ATSaveCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SaveCell"]; in viewDidLoad

Comment: @WilliamGeorge that's probably an answer, not just a comment

Comment: @wootage this prevents a crash, but the cell is not the same as the prototype i made in the storyboard.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge I am only returning 1 cell.

Comment: @pka2012 prevent or cause crash?

Comment: @wootage what you suggested prevented a crash, but the cell is just empty. I have a static label defined in the sb which doesnt show up.

Comment: hm... I have in mind something that might work:
1) remove cell.textLabel.text from cellForRowAtIndexPath
2) drag outlet in your cell class and create some setter or method to style the cell
3) use - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 [(ATSaveCell*)cell yourStyleMethos]
}

Comment: Are you using `static cells` instead of `prototype cell` in the storyboard? Check your UITableView Content Type.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge how would i check that?

Comment: In the storyboard, click on your table view. Click "Show Attributes Inspector" The first drop down under "Content" with either show `Static Cells` or `Dynamic Prototype`

Comment: They are static cells.

Comment: Does it do what you want id you change it to prototype cells? If so I have added an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is the UITableView is not dequeuing a cell from a storyboard. Try checking that you are using `prototype cells` instead of `static cells`. The UITableView will not dequeue a static cell.

If the problem is that you are always calling `[[ATSaveCell alloc] init]`. The table view will need to if it doesn't have anything the reuse.

From the docs: *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier*

> This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a
>   new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no
>   cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib
>   file, this method returns nil.

Therefore, if there are not enough cells to fit the view, it will always create a new one.